# AJAX HTTP 200 error in Views Field View

Tags: views

I have just installed the Views Field View Module (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view), which enables to append an existing View as a field inside a View.

But when I want to Append a View field, I get an AJAX error (HTTP 200) :

Une erreur HTTP AJAX s'est produite.
Code de statut HTTP : 200
Informations de débogage ci-dessous.
Chemin : /admin/structure/views/view/cat_chisme_liste_des_enfants/preview/default/ajax
StatusText: OK
ResponseText : php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)
... and so on ...

And the field configuration form displayed is not usable.

(Drupal 7.67)

Comment: You should raise this issue on the module issues queue. https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/views_field_view?categories=All after checking it's not a known problem. Make sure you have read all the document relating to this module as well.

Comment: I visited the issue queue : it does not seem to be a known problem ; what should be the next step ? How can I raise the issue ? (Notice : I have updated my question, including the error message)

Comment: If you are getting a network error it's probably something else to do with your set up and unlikely to be related to this module. It's hard to guess at but I would suspect there is a web service being invoked in the AJAX scope that is not required. If you have some such service in your build that is called from the server, try turning it off.

Comment: Thank you Alfred ; are you thinking of a Module or an Extension ? should I disable them one by one until I find which is causing that ?

Comment: Most likely a module but I don't know how your site is built so can't really say for sure.

Comment: Another thing that occurred to me is that it might be trying to open a DB connection to an inaccessible server. Check for that possibility - eg. logic that switches between live and dev db servers that might not work correctly in AJAX.

Comment: Thank you Alfred, but I doubt of that, because I have a lot of functions which access the DBs (in fact 2 DBs because I use CiviCRM Extension), including Views, Webform + a lot of CiviCRM features, which have worked correctly for years. I am rather thinking of a sort of conflict. I intend to create a test subdomain, and install and test extensions one by one.